# redirect site excluding wp-admin when redirecting each page with individual 301's

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using htaccess to redirect traffic from one site to another using multiple redirects as per below. I am mapping each page so the content is still relevant for SEO purposes.

```
redirect 301 /page https://newsite.co.uk/page
```

I have 407 redirects mapped this way.

I need to also redirect the wordpress home page but if I use `redirect 301 / https://newsite.co.uk` it obviously redirects all traffic. Can anyone point me in the right direction how to redirect the wordpress home page but leaving the wp-admin folder, and all of my custom redirects?

This is the current .htaccess structure:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# START MJB REDIRECTS
redirect 301 /resetpass/ https://www.newsite.co.uk/newpage
redirect 301 /login/ https://www.newsite.co.uk/anothernewpage
407 more redirects...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first this rule:

```
redirect 301 / https://newsite.co.uk
```

Must be placed at the bottom so that it should be the last rule to execute otherwise this will override all other rules and will always execute.

Using `redirect` should be avoided altogether since you already have `mod_rewrite` rules in your .htaccess. So above rule can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newsite.co.uk [L,R=302]
```

Finally if you have access to server config I highly recommend using [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) since you have large numbers of URIs to redirect.

PS: Only after you verify redirect is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the RewriteRule as mentioned would keep the existing link structure? We are merging two sites and the new site has a different structure.

Comment: No `RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newsite.co.uk [L,R=302]` will redirect home page only to new site's home page. Similarly you can use: `RewriteRule ^resetpass/?$ https://newsite.co.uk/newpage [NC,L,R=302]`